# docker: why are images per machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm trying to learn docker-machine and docker swarm. After creating and running a few machines, I discovered that the docker images are actually per machine. This means that one has to pull/build images for each machine that's in a cluster.

This sounds like a waste of time/space for me. What's the logic behind this?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. If you create a service on a docker swarm, the images will be downloaded automatically in the backrgound on any node running the desired image. I suggest reading the swarm mode tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Correction. Docker 1.12 still requires the images to be present on each node before doing `docker service create`. That's inconvenient as  you write but on the other hand it's the only way to make sure that services are restarted on some other node if the main node that had the images goes down.